# Remove security settings and reset layout and insert options on all items in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a Sitecore 6.5 project, where I have upgraded all the content from an earlier version. But something seems to have gone wrong in the upgrade process, which has caused all items to have a security setting of `extranet\everyone` which have `deny read` access, even though that is not the case. Also the layout and insert options needs to get reset and taken the values from the templates standard values.

I could do this manually in the Sitecore UI, but that would take quite some time, as there is 3000+ items.

Is there any way I can patch this with a quickfix of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

You could either write a script in ASPX that does this for you or install the PowerShell module and script it with that.
It depends on your experience and on which tools you have available.
Unfortunately there is no built-in method for resetting layouts and insert options on all content items.